# How do I run SuperCollider?

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-11.04

I installed SuperCollider. However it didn't appear in my app menu. Also, I can't make up any good command which could start the interpreter.

How should I run it?

Comment: Exactly which package did you install?

Comment: See: http://blog.artfwo.net/2008/05/supercollider-for-human-beings.html

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt install supercollider
```

and now I can launch the IDE either with:

```
scide
```

or from the dash menu (reachable by pressing the "Windows key") by searching for "supercollider".

You could find the command by doing:

```
dpkg -l | grep supercol
```

which shows:

```
ii  supercollider                                               1:3.10.0+repack-1ubuntu2                         amd64        real time audio synthesis programming language
ii  supercollider-common                                        1:3.10.0+repack-1ubuntu2                         all          common files for SuperCollider
ii  supercollider-ide                                           1:3.10.0+repack-1ubuntu2                         amd64        integrated development environment for supercollider audio system
ii  supercollider-language                                      1:3.10.0+repack-1ubuntu2                         amd64        real time audio synthesis programming language
ii  supercollider-server                                        1:3.10.0+repack-1ubuntu2                         amd64        real time audio synthesis server
ii  supercollider-supernova                                     1:3.10.0+repack-1ubuntu2                         amd64        real time audio synthesis server (multiprocessor version)
```

and then:

```
dpkg -L supercollider-ide
```

contains:

```
/usr/bin/scide
```

How to run it from the command line without the IDE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65360414/how-to-play-a-supercollider-file-non-interactively-from-the-terminal-command-lin

Answer (score 0):

You don't say *how* you installed supercollider, so I guess you downloaded the source code from the main website? If so, then you don't get any menu entry but you do get the commands. Run the terminal command `sclang` to get a bare SuperCollider commandline. Or you may well have created the gedit/emacs/vim plugins when you compiled everything (it depends on compile settings) - if so, see the docs for how to start those in SuperCollider-mode.

**However**, my recommendation is **not** to install from source code but to use [the SuperCollider PPA here](https://launchpad.net/~supercollider/+archive/ppa) (the webpage includes instructions). When you do that, it **additionally** gives you menu items for "SuperCollider Emacs" and "SuperCollider Vim" which make it a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Since recently a dedicated IDE is available for Ubuntu.

Check out this article:

http://scacinto.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/new-supercollider-on-xubuntu/